# IndexError: list index out of range error during permutation

Tags: python-3.x

I have an `(4, 10, 3)` array, which I want to brute force all possible permutations for each individual row of each 4 arrays.

```
reshaped_input_data: 
[[[-217.90978582 -129.626772   1062.88      ]
[-354.14919316   55.50499093 1062.88      ]
[-355.55146902  285.35924775 1062.88      ]
[-221.58099168  472.13948482 1062.88      ]
[  -3.40993     544.502      1062.88      ]
[ 215.62778582  474.806772   1062.88      ]
[ 351.86719316  289.67500907 1062.88      ]
[ 353.26946902   59.82075225 1062.88      ]
[ 219.29899168 -126.95948482 1062.88      ]
[   1.12793    -199.322      1062.88      ]]

[[-240.60918575 -163.9358504  1037.68      ]
[-392.67976377   41.09073595 1037.68      ]
[-395.19584194  296.34557168 1037.68      ]
[-247.19636392  504.32998532 1037.68      ]
[  -5.2121      585.601      1037.68      ]
[ 238.32718575  509.1158504  1037.68      ]
[ 390.39776377  304.08926405 1037.68      ]
[ 392.91384194   48.83442832 1037.68      ]
[ 244.91436392 -159.14998532 1037.68      ]
[   2.9301     -240.421      1037.68      ]]

[[-247.20744713 -173.74978426 1014.06      ]
[-403.78635494   37.02945741 1014.06      ]
[-406.56842258  299.58821882 1014.06      ]
[-254.49099477  513.63797715 1014.06      ]
[  -5.64248     597.419      1014.06      ]
[ 244.92544713  518.92978426 1014.06      ]
[ 401.50435494  308.15054259 1014.06      ]
[ 404.28642258   45.59178118 1014.06      ]
[ 252.20899477 -168.45797715 1014.06      ]
[   3.36048    -252.239      1014.06      ]]

[[-249.41427208 -176.4380601   989.953     ]
[-407.15184272   36.15173573  989.953     ]
[-409.80707125  300.85631115  989.953     ]
[-256.3657506   516.56751532  989.953     ]
[  -5.43725     600.891       989.953     ]
[ 247.13227208  521.6180601   989.953     ]
[ 404.86984272  309.02826427  989.953     ]
[ 407.52507125   44.32368885  989.953     ]
[ 254.0837506  -171.38751532  989.953     ]
[   3.15525    -255.711       989.953     ]]] <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (4, 10, 3)
```

The permutation is performed as following:

```
def brute_force(reshaped_input_data):

  count = 0
  odometer = [0, 0, 0, 0]
  roll_sequance = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]  # The sequence of positions by which to roll the odometer
  expired = False

  while not expired:
      brute_force_result = reshaped_input_data[[0, 1, 2, 3], [odometer]]

      for i in roll_sequance :
          count = count + 1
          if odometer[i] < 9:
              odometer[i] += 1
              break
          else:
              if i == 0:  # Done all permutations
                expired = True
                odometer[i] = 0
      print('i: ', i, 'odometer[i]: ', odometer[i])

    # Put row number and its pos in a dictionary
    brute_force_result = {(row, pos): reshaped_input_data[row, pos] for (row, pos) in enumerate(odometer)}
    print('count: ', count, 'brute_force_result:', brute_force_result, type(brute_force_result))

    yield bruteForceResult
```

As result for first permutation, I get e.g., which looks fully ok:

```
roll_sequance[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0] <class 'list'>

i:  1 odometer[i]:  1
count:  1 brute_force_result: {(0, 0): array([-217.90978582, -129.626772  , 1062.88      ]), (1, 1): 
array([-392.67976377,   41.09073595, 1037.68      ]), (2, 0): array([-247.20744713, -173.74978426, 1014.06      ]), (3, 0): array([-249.41427208, -176.4380601 ,  989.953     ])} <class 'dict'>
i:  1 odometer[i]:  2
count:  2 brute_force_result: {(0, 0): array([-217.90978582, -129.626772  , 1062.88      ]), (1, 2): 
array([-395.19584194,  296.34557168, 1037.68      ]), (2, 0): array([-247.20744713, -173.74978426, 1014.06      ]), (3, 0): array([-249.41427208, -176.4380601 ,  989.953     ])} <class 'dict'>
i:  1 odometer[i]:  3
count:  3 brute_force_result: {(0, 0): array([-217.90978582, -129.626772  , 1062.88      ]), (1, 3): 
array([-247.19636392,  504.32998532, 1037.68      ]), (2, 0): array([-247.20744713, -173.74978426, 1014.06      ]), (3, 0): array([-249.41427208, -176.4380601 ,  989.953     ])} <class 'dict'>
i:  1 odometer[i]:  4
count:  4 brute_force_result: {(0, 0): array([-217.90978582, -129.626772  , 1062.88      ]), (1, 4): 
array([  -5.2121,  585.601 , 1037.68  ]), (2, 0): array([-247.20744713, -173.74978426, 1014.06      ]), (3, 0): array([-249.41427208, -176.4380601 ,  989.953     ])} <class 'dict'>
i:  1 odometer[i]:  5
count:  5 brute_force_result: {(0, 0): array([-217.90978582, -129.626772  , 1062.88      ]), (1, 5): 
array([ 238.32718575,  509.1158504 , 1037.68      ]), (2, 0): array([-247.20744713, -173.74978426, 1014.06      ]), (3, 0): array([-249.41427208, -176.4380601 ,  989.953     ])} <class 'dict'>
i:  1 odometer[i]:  6
count:  6 brute_force_result: {(0, 0): array([-217.90978582, -129.626772  , 1062.88      ]), (1, 6): 
array([ 390.39776377,  304.08926405, 1037.68      ]), (2, 0): array([-247.20744713, -173.74978426, 1014.06      ]), (3, 0): array([-249.41427208, -176.4380601 ,  989.953     ])} <class 'dict'>
i:  1 odometer[i]:  7
count:  7 brute_force_result: {(0, 0): array([-217.90978582, -129.626772  , 1062.88      ]), (1, 7): 
array([ 392.91384194,   48.83442832, 1037.68      ]), (2, 0): array([-247.20744713, -173.74978426, 1014.06      ]), (3, 0): array([-249.41427208, -176.4380601 ,  989.953     ])} <class 'dict'>
i:  1 odometer[i]:  8
count:  8 brute_force_result: {(0, 0): array([-217.90978582, -129.626772  , 1062.88      ]), (1, 8): 
array([ 244.91436392, -159.14998532, 1037.68      ]), (2, 0): array([-247.20744713, -173.74978426, 1014.06      ]), (3, 0): array([-249.41427208, -176.4380601 ,  989.953     ])} <class 'dict'>
i:  1 odometer[i]:  9
count:  9 brute_force_result: {(0, 0): array([-217.90978582, -129.626772  , 1062.88      ]), (1, 9): 
array([   2.9301, -240.421 , 1037.68  ]), (2, 0): array([-247.20744713, -173.74978426, 1014.06      ]), (3, 0): array([-249.41427208, -176.4380601 ,  989.953     ])} <class 'dict'>
```

The issue occurs after `1107th` run. I get an indexing error, which I could not understand the reason

```
if odometer[i] < 9:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

The sequence should be in length 4 not 10, since it rolls over 4 arrays. Therefore, the issue is solved.

```
roll_sequance = [1, 2, 3, 0]
```